# Undefined responseText in jsonp request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I 'm using $.ajax to send a jsonp request to an api prepared by a server on https.

My script is as follows:

```
var sUrl = "https://localhost/api/" + document.getElementById('query').value +
           "?apikey=c13eb63d-b9ee-4ceb-89fe-944072deddbb&fmt=json&limit=&query=" + document.getElementById('query').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: sUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        async:false,
        crossDomain : true,
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                alert(jqXHR);
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
            });
```

My request will be send and I can receive the result in my browser and this is my response body:

{"relatedid_restriction":null,"purpose":"mitigation","asn":null,"rir":null,"alternativeid":null,"cc":null,"detecttime":"2014-04-08T17:34:31Z","address":"google.com","alternativeid_restriction":null,"id":"2bdd4e07-26ba-4dc2-99a8-bdea54bf3d4f","guid":"everyone","severity":null,"assessment":"search","rdata":null,"description":"search google.com","asn_desc":null,"relatedid":null,"reporttime":"2014-04-08T17:34:31Z","confidence":"50","restriction":"private","prefix":null} {"relatedid_restriction":null,"purpose":"mitigation","asn":null,"rir":null,"alternativeid":null,"cc":null,"detecttime":"2014-04-08T17:35:14Z","address":"google.com","alternativeid_restriction":null,"id":"1df23bea-ab15-4410-aab4-d2c538a385fd","guid":"everyone","severity":null,"assessment":"search","rdata":null,"description":"search google.com","asn_desc":null,"relatedid":null,"reporttime":"2014-04-08T17:35:14Z","confidence":"50","restriction":"private","prefix":null}

Now the first alert "alert(jqXHR);" returns [object Object] but the second one "alert(jqXHR.responseText);" returns undefined.

How can I retreive the response body text in my javascript?

Thanks

Comment: that response is not jsonp. please research what JSONP is. It's very different from your normal ajax request, heck, it isn't an ajax request at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jsonp you need to make a function call. Something like this:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . "(" . json_encode($DATA) . ");";
```

because a jsonp will need to call a function. I think jQuery will add a GET variable with `callback` as the name.

Than you can do this:

```
jsonp: "callback",
success : function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

More info and examples: http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/

Answer (score 0):

From jquery documentation:

> The text and xml types return the data with no processing. The data is simply passed on to the success handler, either through the responseText or responseXML property of the jqXHR object, respectively.

That is, responseText is only valid when `datatype="text"`, so either change datatype if you don't need jsonp or use first parameter in your complete callback, which should be object representing your json response